# pandas dataframe append string to id column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file loaded in pandas and I want to append the id with a string

here is my code to do so.

```
for index_data, row_data in dataset.iterrows():
      dataset.set_value(index_data,'person_id', "u_"+ row_data['person_id'].tostring())
```

so basically instead of 1,2...n what I want to have is u_1,u_2,u_3 but I keep getting this error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: 'u_'
```

any solution?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because `person_id` is an integer column, and `set_value` would expect a value of the *same* dtype as the column being mutated. Since you pass a string, the error is thrown (it expected a long, not a string).

Here's the pandaic way of doing it - vectorized string concatenation:

```
dataset['person_id'] = 'u_' + dataset['person_id'].astype(str)
```